# declaring functions that take template parameters

Tags: c++, templates

I want to define a helper function that takes a template parameter. I have tried making a templated function for this, but it does not compile. Any idea what I'm doing wrong? Here's the code I tried.

```
// vectors are great, but lack a find method. Implement one as a helper.
template<class T> bool vec_find(vector<T> &v, T obj)
{
    vector<T>::iterator s;
    for (s = v.begin(); s < v.end(); s++)
    {
        if (*s == obj)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Did you place this in a header file?  What's the compiler error?

Comment: Use `std::find`.

Comment: I think you'll need a `typename` before `vector<T>::iterator`. Also, you should never use `s < v.end()` with iterators. For vectors, where storage is contiguous, it might work fine, but then when you move to something like `std::list`, you'll get unexpected results. Better yet, you can used ranged-for or `std::for_each`.

Comment: Or you could use `std::binary_search` when your vectors are sorted.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where and why do I have to put the "template" and "typename" keywords?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords)

Answer (score 1):

Presumably, your compiler told you what the problem was. Mine said:

```
test.cpp:7:5: error: need ‘typename’ before ‘std::vector<T>::iterator’ because ‘std::vector<T>’ is a dependent scope
```

So to fix it, add `typename` before `vector<T>::iterator`:

```
typename vector<T>::iterator s;
^^^^^^^^
```

In general, you need that whenever the scope of a type name depends on a template parameter; until the template is instantiated, the compiler doesn't know how `vector<T>` will be defined, and so needs to be told that a name scoped inside it refers to a type rather than something else.

However, there is a good reason why `vector` doesn't have a `find` method: the C++ library separates containers from the algorithms that act on them, so that any algorithm can act on any suitable sequence. You want to use `std::find` for this:

```
return std::find(v.begin(), v.end(), obj) != v.end();
```

Comment: I just realized the OP never said that the problem was in the function header. For whatever reason, I thought they did :p

Comment: Thanks! std::find() was a great solution.